# Wifi connection constantly cutting in and out 22.04.3

Tags: networking, wireless

Usually takes several attempts to get connected in the first place, then will stop working although the wifi indicator will stay full bars.

Edit: it's the only device in the house that has problems on the wifi
Edit: here is an exerpt from ping google.com

```
64 bytes from sea09s28-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.78): icmp_seq=4100 ttl=60 time=145 ms
[...]
From user-UX330UAK (192.168.1.177) icmp_seq=4101 Destination Host Unreachable
[...]
64 bytes from sea09s28-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.33.78): icmp_seq=4173 ttl=60 time=1044 ms
```

Comment: You've not said which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product (server? desktop? flavor?) or what kernel stack you're using (*this is selected by installation media used & product details you've not mentioned*).  By switching kernel stack you can sometimes get different behavior (as different kernel means different kernel modules are used; kernel modules commonly called *drivers*).  Please tell us & don't make us guess.  Was it like this in the *live* session, or has changes occurred?  today only? or please provide details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.